Generating smooth curves in JFreeChart using XYBezierRenderer or XYCardinalSplineRenderer
I am trying to generate a graph using JFreeChart to display temperature and humidity data. Initially, I used XYSplineRenderer, but it was going out of bounds. After researching on Stack Overflow, I found a suggestion to use XYBezierRenderer, seen in JFreeChart setAutoRange when XYSplineRenderer is used as rendered and here. However, even with XYBezierRenderer, the results were not satisfactory, as there were sharp turns at tension 0.05 and precision 5.
Here is the code I am using to create the chart:
private JFreeChart createMultiAxisChart(List<EntityAuditDto> reportsData, Map<String, String> attributes, TemperatureStatistics temperatureStats, HumidityStatistics humidityStatistics) {
List<EntityAuditDto> reportData = generateDummyData();
XYDataset temperatureDataset = createMultiTemperatureDataset(reportData);
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
                            "Temperature & Humidity",
                            "Time",
                             "Temperature (°C)",
                             temperatureDataset,true,true,false);
    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
    plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
    plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(true);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.GRAY);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.GRAY);

    Font axisLabelFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 12);
    Font tickLabelFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 10);
    Color axisLabelColor = Color.BLACK;

    DateAxis dateAxis = new DateAxis("Time");
    dateAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    dateAxis.setAutoTickUnitSelection(true);
    dateAxis.setAutoRange(true);
    dateAxis.setLabelFont(axisLabelFont);
    dateAxis.setTickLabelFont(tickLabelFont);
    dateAxis.setLabelPaint(axisLabelColor);
    dateAxis.setTickLabelPaint(axisLabelColor);
    plot.setDomainAxis(dateAxis);

    XYBezierRenderer tempRenderer = new XYBezierRenderer(5,0.05);
    for (int i = 0; i < temperatureDataset.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
        tempRenderer.setSeriesPaint(i, getSeriesColor(i));
        tempRenderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(i, false);
    }
    plot.setRenderer(0, tempRenderer);

    NumberAxis tempAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    tempAxis.setLabelFont(axisLabelFont);
    tempAxis.setTickLabelFont(tickLabelFont);
    tempAxis.setLabelPaint(axisLabelColor);
    tempAxis.setTickLabelPaint(axisLabelColor);
    double minTemperature = calculateMinTemperature(temperatureStats);
    double maxTemperature = calculateMaxTemperature(temperatureStats);
    tempAxis.setRange(0, 100);
    tempAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
    tempAxis.setLowerMargin(0.05);
    tempAxis.setUpperMargin(0.05);


    XYDataset humidityDataset = createMultiHumidityDataset(reportData);
    NumberAxis humidityAxis = new NumberAxis("Humidity (%)");

    double minHumidity = calculateMinHumidity(humidityStatistics);
    double maxHumidity = calculateMaxHumidity(humidityStatistics);
    humidityAxis.setLabelFont(axisLabelFont);
    humidityAxis.setTickLabelFont(tickLabelFont);
    humidityAxis.setLabelPaint(axisLabelColor);
    humidityAxis.setTickLabelPaint(axisLabelColor);
    humidityAxis.setRange(0, 100);
    humidityAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(10));
    humidityAxis.setUpperMargin(0.05);
    humidityAxis.setLowerMargin(0.05);
    humidityAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);

    plot.setRangeAxis(1, humidityAxis);
    plot.setDataset(1, humidityDataset);
    plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1, 1);

    XYBezierRenderer humidityRenderer = new XYBezierRenderer(5,0.05);
    for (int i = 0; i < humidityDataset.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
        humidityRenderer.setSeriesPaint(i, getSeriesColor(i + temperatureDataset.getSeriesCount()));
        humidityRenderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(i, false);
    }
    plot.setRenderer(1, humidityRenderer);

    LegendItemCollection legendItems = new LegendItemCollection();
    XYItemRenderer renderer0 = plot.getRenderer(0);
    XYItemRenderer renderer1 = plot.getRenderer(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < temperatureDataset.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
        Paint seriesPaint = renderer0.getSeriesPaint(i);
        LegendItem legendItem = new LegendItem(
                temperatureDataset.getSeriesKey(i).toString(),
                "",
                "",
                "",
                new Rectangle(10, 10),
                seriesPaint
        );
        legendItem.setLabelPaint(seriesPaint);
        legendItems.add(legendItem);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < humidityDataset.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
        Paint seriesPaint = renderer1.getSeriesPaint(i);
        LegendItem legendItem = new LegendItem(
                humidityDataset.getSeriesKey(i).toString(),
                "",
                "",
                "",
                new Rectangle(10, 10),
                seriesPaint
        );
        legendItem.setLabelPaint(seriesPaint);
        legendItems.add(legendItem);
    }

    plot.setFixedLegendItems(legendItems);
    return chart;
}

and custom data is generated as
private List<EntityAuditDto> generateDummyData() {
    List<EntityAuditDto> dummyData = new ArrayList<>();
    Random random = new Random();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd   HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -30); // Start 30 days ago    // Generate data every 7.5 hours (96 points over 30 days)
    int hoursPerReading = 7;
    int minutesPerReading = 30;

    for (int i = 0; i < 96; i++) {
        EntityAuditDto dto = new EntityAuditDto();

        // Generate timestamp
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, hoursPerReading);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesPerReading);
        dto.setDateTime(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

        // Generate data with realistic variations
        double timeProgress = i / 95.0; // Normalized time progress (0 to 1)
        double dailyCycle = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * timeProgress * 4); // 4 complete cycles over the period
        double weeklyCycle = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * timeProgress * (4.0/7)); // 4/7 cycles (4 weeks) over the period

        // Generate values for each sensor within specified ranges
        double t1Base = 55 + 35 * dailyCycle + 5 * weeklyCycle; // 10 to 100
        double t2Base = 45 + 10 * dailyCycle + 3 * weeklyCycle; // 30 to 60
        double t3Base = 15 + 10 * dailyCycle + 3 * weeklyCycle; // 0 to 30
        double h1Base = 75 + 20 * dailyCycle + 3 * weeklyCycle; // 50 to 100
        double h2Base = 35 + 10 * dailyCycle + 3 * weeklyCycle; // 20 to 50

        // Add random noise and ensure values are within specified ranges
        dto.setT1(String.format("%.2f", clamp(t1Base + random.nextGaussian() * 3, 10, 100)));
        dto.setT2(String.format("%.2f", clamp(t2Base + random.nextGaussian() * 2, 30, 60)));
        dto.setT3(String.format("%.2f", clamp(t3Base + random.nextGaussian() * 2, 0, 30)));
        dto.setH1(String.format("%.2f", clamp(h1Base + random.nextGaussian() * 3, 50, 100)));
        dto.setH2(String.format("%.2f", clamp(h2Base + random.nextGaussian() * 2, 20, 50)));

        dummyData.add(dto);
    }

    return dummyData;
}

// Helper method to clamp values between min and max
private double clamp(double value, double min, double max) {
    return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, value));
}` .

The results for the above data is as this:

I have tried with various precison and tension values. But finally at XYBezierRenderer(5,0.05) getting some better results. The forum had a suggestion to use a custom class XYCardinalSplineRenderer, which I tried and was working somewhat better. Results with it were good at tension 0.05 and segments 16? . I think the solution was back 2014 and it is not included in jfreechart. Can any one help me with this?

I think the latest XYBezierRenderer was merged here.

What happens when you use the current version?

@trashgod I have attached the oytput image in question. Not getting smooth curves.

@Kkv: I just wanted to be sure your image reflected the current version; links updated; please [edit] to correct any errors..
